# how to make the bigger background not show scroll on page

Tags: html, css

specifically for this page:

http://www.intimeahygieia.com/proizvodi/intimea-teen/

I would like it to not show scrollbar on buttom of the browser, like here:

http://www.intimeahygieia.com/proizvodi/intimea/

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the CSS style of the `<div>` (or whatever you use) as *background* (the element with scrollbars) following CSS rules:

```
overflow-x: hidden; 
overflow-y: auto;
```

Note that it can be applied to the `<body>` element too (I guess this is your case).

Comment: `overflow-y: auto` is default

Comment: @binarious Just wanted to be explicit! :)

Comment: @Adriano Thanks, but if I put that on body it never shop y scroll like on another link

Comment: @MkDizajn if you put on body it'll show the vertical scrollbar as needed but it won't show the horizontal one. If it depends on the content you're showing you'd better to apply that rules to the inner container.

Comment: @Adriano thanks, I will have to do more with backend that is generating the html output. thanks for help!